# Google FireStore Key File protection

Tags: c#, wpf, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing a WPF application that uses Google FireStore as Cloud Storage. I have added a somekey.json in my project in order to establish connection. When I Run application the file get exported to the bin folder. Is there any other way to connect to FireStore without the file? Like using in Code Credentials.

Comment: Which keys are you referring to. Are you talking about the config values?

Comment: If you are talking about the `google-services.json` file that you download from the Firebase console, you'll want to have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Everyone there is saying that I should use rules there. Actually the Firestore rules are not working. even on Blocked mode, data is still accessible

Comment: I was mostly trying to clarify what you mean by `somekey.json`. If that is `google-services.json`, my answer I linked explains why that is not a security risk. If you can access the database even with `false` rules, that might mean you're using mechanism that provides administrative credentials.

Answer (score 0):

YES YOU CAN DO IT WITH MD5 Encryption
save MD5 AS STRING IN YOUR APPLICATION
CREATE STRINGS AND FIRESTORE VERIABEL

```
 string projectId;
        FirestoreDb fireStoreDb;
        string googleJs;
```

```
private void wirteAuthFile() {
string hash = "fts";
string auth = "CCfjJhf9p/4prFI4e3RIk6v0S3QXbTcO1CQP66Kk=";
File.WriteAllText("SOFTWAREAUTH.dll", auth);
using (StreamReader readtext = new StreamReader("SOFTWAREAUTH.dll"))
{string readText = readtext.ReadLine();
googleJs = (Decrypition(readText));}
File.WriteAllText("SOFTWAREAUTH.dll", googleJs);
ConnectFirestore();
}
```

```
   private static string Decrypition(string text)
        {
            string hash = "fts";
            byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(text);
            using (MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                byte[] keys = md5.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hash));
                using (TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tripleDES = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider() { Key = keys, Mode = CipherMode.ECB, Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7 })
                {
                    ICryptoTransform transform = tripleDES.CreateDecryptor();
                    byte[] results = transform.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);
                    return UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(results);
                }
            }
        }
```

HERE YOU CAN CONNECT WITH FIRESTORE

```
     private void ConnectFirestore() {
            string filepath = "SOFTWAREAUTH.dll";
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", filepath);
            projectId = "shopshopf";
            fireStoreDb = FirestoreDb.Create(projectId);
           File.Delete(filepath);
        }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).